Formatting chat message array to add protocol and date
I'm attempting to add two objects according to the message state.
When is the first message from that day, it will add an object before that message that contains the date. The protocol will be added if the next message has a different protocol, or if the chat has ended.

Protocol object will always be added before the change of the protocol
Dates will be added before the first message from that day

This is the object:
const chatMessages = [  
  {
    "protocol": "9313478261",
    "msgDate": "2024-01-30T12:58:32"
  },
  {
    "protocol": "9313478261",
    "msgDate": "2024-01-30T12:58:44"
  },
  {
    "protocol": "9313478261",
    "msgDate": "2024-01-30T13:18:25"
  },
  {
    "protocol": "9313478261",
    "msgDate": "2024-01-30T13:18:35"
  },
  {
    "protocol": "9313478261",
    "msgDate": "2024-01-31T10: 50: 26"
  },
  {
    "protocol": "9313478261",
    "msgDate": "2024-02-02T11: 18: 21"
  },
  {
    "protocol": "39128391231",
    "msgDate": "2024-02-03T12:58:32"
  },
  {
    "protocol": "39128391231",
    "msgDate": "2024-02-03T13:58:32"
  },
  {
    "protocol": "87382713812",
    "msgDate": "2024-02-03T14:58:32"
  },
  {
    "protocol": "87382713812",
    "msgDate": "2024-02-03T15:58:32"
  },
]


This is what I'm attempting to achieve:

const chatMessages = [  
  {
    "type": "info",
    "date": "2024-01-30"
  },
  {
    "protocol": "9313478261",
    "msgDate": "2024-01-30T12:58:44"
  },
  {
    "protocol": "9313478261",
    "msgDate": "2024-01-30T13:18:25"
  },
  {
    "protocol": "9313478261",
    "msgDate": "2024-01-30T13:18:35"
  },
  {
    "type": "info",
    "date": "2024-01-31"
  },
  {
    "protocol": "9313478261",
    "msgDate": "2024-01-31T10: 50: 26"
  },
  {
    "type": "info",
    "date": "2024-02-02"
  },
  {
    "protocol": "9313478261",
    "msgDate": "2024-02-02T11: 18: 21"
  },
  {
    "type": "info",
    "date": "Protocol is 9313478261"
  },
  {
    "type": "info",
    "date": "2024-02-03"
  },
  {
    "protocol": "39128391231",
    "msgDate": "2024-02-03T12:58:32"
  },
  {
    "protocol": "39128391231",
    "msgDate": "2024-02-03T13:58:32"
  },
  {
    "type": "info",
    "date": "Protocol is 39128391231"
  },
  {
    "protocol": "87382713812",
    "msgDate": "2024-02-03T14:58:32"
  },
  {
    "type": "info",
    "date": "2024-02-04"
  },
  {
    "protocol": "87382713812",
    "msgDate": "2024-02-04T15:58:32"
  },
]

The code I have:
let lastProtocol = null;
let currentDate = null;

const modifiedMessages = chatMessages.reduce((acc, message) => {
  const messageDate = new Date(message.msgDate);
  const messageProtocol = message.protocol;

  if (!currentDate || messageDate.toDateString() !== currentDate.toDateString()) {
    acc.push({ info: true });
    currentDate = messageDate;
  }
  
  if (lastProtocol !== messageProtocol) {
    acc.push({ protocol: lastProtocol });
    lastProtocol = messageProtocol;
  }

  acc.push(message);
  return acc;
}, []);


modifiedMessages.push({ protocol: lastProtocol });

console.log(modifiedMessages);

But the protocol and dates are not correctly added:
[{
  "info": true
}, {
  "protocol": null
}, {
  "protocol": "9313478261",
  "msgDate": "2024-01-30T12:58:32"
}, {
  "protocol": "9313478261",
  "msgDate": "2024-01-30T12:58:44"
}, {
  "protocol": "9313478261",
  "msgDate": "2024-01-30T13:18:25"
}, {
  "protocol": "9313478261",
  "msgDate": "2024-01-30T13:18:35"
}, {
  "info": true
}, {
  "protocol": "9313478261",
  "msgDate": "2024-01-31T10: 50: 26"
}, {
  "protocol": "9313478261",
  "msgDate": "2024-02-02T11: 18: 21"
}, {
  "info": true
}, {
  "protocol": "9313478261"
}, {
  "protocol": "39128391231",
  "msgDate": "2024-02-03T12:58:32"
}, {
  "protocol": "39128391231",
  "msgDate": "2024-02-03T13:58:32"
}, {
  "protocol": "39128391231"
}, {
  "protocol": "87382713812",
  "msgDate": "2024-02-03T14:58:32"
}, {
  "protocol": "87382713812",
  "msgDate": "2024-02-03T15:58:32"
}, {
  "protocol": "87382713812"
}] 


What is not working?

The protocols object are not inserted after the last message of that protocol, and the dates are being wrongly added

To resolve the issue, ensure dates are extracted in YYYY-MM-DD format, add a type: info object for new days, and insert protocol info when protocols change. At the end, append a final protocol info object if still active. Below is the corrected code:
let lastProtocol = null;
let currentDate = null;

const modifiedMessages = chatMessages.reduce((acc, message) => {
  const messageDate = new Date(message.msgDate).toISOString().split('T')[0];
  const messageProtocol = message.protocol;

  if (currentDate !== messageDate) {
    acc.push({ type: "info", date: messageDate });
    currentDate = messageDate;
  }

  if (lastProtocol !== messageProtocol) {
    if (lastProtocol !== null) {
      acc.push({ type: "info", date: `Protocol is ${lastProtocol}` });
    }
    lastProtocol = messageProtocol;
  }

  acc.push(message);

  return acc;
}, []);

if (lastProtocol !== null) {
  modifiedMessages.push({ type: "info", date: `Protocol is ${lastProtocol}` });
}

console.log(modifiedMessages);

